# Repetitive structure in Clojure

Tags: clojure, hiccup

It is said in the book "Web Development with Clojure" that the code

```
(defn registration-page []
    (layout/common
        (form-to [:post "/register"]
            (label "id" "screen name")
            (text-field "id")
            [:br]
            (label "pass" "password")
            (password-field "pass")
            [:br]
            (label "pass1" "retype password")
            (password-field "pass1")
            [:br]
            (submit-button "create account"))))
```

can be rewritten using a helper function as following:

```
(defn control [field name text]
  (list (on-error name format-error)
        (label name text)
        (field name)
        [:br]))

(defn registration-page []
  (layout/common
    (form-to [:post "/register"]
      (control text-field :id "screen name")
      (control password-field :pass "Password")
      (control password-field :pass1 "Retype Password")
      (submit-button "Create Account"))))
```

My question is: In the alternative code, why the value of the parameter *name* is not a string? For example, why is it (control text-field **:id** "screen name"), not (control text-field **"id"** "screen name") ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Hiccup and I don't have the book you mentioned. But by reading Hiccup source code, you can find:

[Label](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup/blob/1.0.4/src/hiccup/form.clj#L108) is calling [make-id](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup/blob/1.0.4/src/hiccup/form.clj#L21) function which it calls [as-str](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup/blob/1.0.4/src/hiccup/util.clj#L39). Have a look at that function and see what it is doing.

```
(defn ^String as-str
  "Converts its arguments into a string using to-str."
  [& xs]
  (apply str (map to-str xs)))
```

That will leads you to ***ToString*** protocol.

Pass strings instead of keywords in the snippet you posted and see what is happening!

Source code is the best documentation we can have!